# Limitations in chrome workspaces

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, workspace, developer-tools

I want to build an entire layout directly from chrome dev tools. So I came over workspaces in chrome dev tools.

But there are 2 limitations I'm facing after I map styles and html to file system resource

1. If I do some html change from elements panel - like edit html or delete a node - it is not mapped to my workspace html file so that I can save it - is there a way to see such changes??
2. After I've mapped by css file - and my local css file does not have a rule for a selector say

   ## wrapper{ font-family:"Courier New"}

then I can't persist the change I make from elements panel by directly selecting an element.

See images below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry, what are you asking?

Answer (score 0):

"Only styles defined in an external CSS file can be saved. Changes to element.style or to inline styles are not persisted. (If you have inline styles, they can be changed on the Sources panel.)"

From https://developers.google.com/web/tools/setup/setup-workflow:

Comment: how about syncing between html changes in elements tab and sources tab??

Comment: Not sure what you mean? If you've mapped an external stylesheet, then you should be able to select an element, change anything in the elements tab, then have that persist back to the stylesheet (which you should be able to see in the sources tab). What it won't do is add new declarations to your mapped stylesheet.

Comment: i want to do dom changes or html changes in from elements tab (not style changes) and persist them somehow

Comment: Sorry :( "Only style changes in the Elements panel are persisted; changes to the DOM are not persisted." from the same link.